# Virtual Directory in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, virtual-directory

We got 2 websites (WebsiteA and WebsiteB). On WebsiteA, I chose "Add a virtual directory" and selected a folder on WebsiteB to be my physical path. The Alias is the same as the target.

[image: Virtual directory created on WebsiteA]

As you can see, on WebsiteB, the folder "Main" is already an application.

[image: Application Main on WebsiteB]

In the forum, I saw that people with the same error forgot to convert the folder as an application, but mine is already done didn't?

[image]

I found that right clicking on my virtual directory (first image) and selecting "Convert to application" seems to work. Is it the right way to do this? By doing this, do I lose my virtual directory? I don't want to use duplicate content (if I edit something in the "Main" folder on websiteB, I don't want to edit the "Main" folder on WebsiteA manually too). I have been told to use the virtual directory as it's supposed to do the job, but none of us has used it before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directories and applications work a little bit different in IIS > 6.0.  Virtual directories used to be self contained applications in IIS 6.0, so your web.config file would be fine.  But in IIS 7.0 and above, a virtual directory is just that, a pointer to a directory.

If you are looking for the same effect of a virtual directory as in IIS 6.0, you'll need to create an application underneath WebsiteA, not a virtual directory.  A virtual directory in IIS 7 and above runs as a directory underneath the parent website, not as a separate application.